# Is there one git command to create a branch, switch to it, and link it to it's remote counterpart?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

Right now when I want to do a quick fix on my project, I do this:

```
# create and switch to this new branch
git checkout -b fixes-20130828-01
# push the new branch back to the origin
git push origin fixes-20130828-01
# link local and remote branches
git --set-upstream fixes-20130828-01 origin/fixes-20130828-01
```

I would like to be able to do the above with something like this:

```
# is there a way to get this to not only create and switch locally,
# but also to link to remote
git checkout --[something] fixes-20130828-01
# and then this would do the actual push to create
# the branch on the origin, now that it's logically linked up
git push
```

This would be easier to use, remember, and easier to explain to new team members, etc., i.e. "You create the new branch, based on your existing one using this command, and then just push it back like you normally do."

Is there an option to do this out of the box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to do it in 2 steps. I don't know of a way to do it in one.

```
git checkout -b my-new-branch
git push -u origin my-new-branch
```

(the -u option sets the upstream tracking.)

Comment: `>I don't know of a way to do it in one` - write an alias like `mycommand = !git checkout -b my-new-branch && git push -u origin my-new-branch`

Comment: Nice - one additional option to remember (-u) but otherwise that seems like just the thing.  @madhead: agreed, although my main use case is explaining to other people new to git (and sometimes new to a lot of things) what to do, so am trying to avoid additional per-machine config.  But thanks.